# Javascript xPath [@StoreName]?

Tags: javascript, xpath

I'm doing some research for a project that I have going on the uses the document.createTreeWalker and I'm looking at a script that uses quite a few xpath's, but I'm curious as to where these come from.  Some are obvious and I have been able to find answers to online, such as [@AttributeName] and [@TagName], but what is [@StoreName], [@AttributeValue1], [@AttributeValue2]...these I have not been able to look up online.

Particularly, I'm looking at these lines and not understanding:

```
thisURL = window.document.location.href.toString();
if(thisURL.search("[@StoreName]") != -1) { //do something }
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question, but there's nothing functionally or syntactically different between `[@AttributeName]` and `[@StoreName]`. They're both predicates that are looking for elements with particular attributes. The first one is looking for `AttributeName` attributes, while the second is looking for `StoreName` attributes.

That said, the code you're showing isn't actually doing any XPath work. It's just looking at whether the URL contains the character sequence **[@StoreName]** using JavaScript's string search function, and doing something if it does.

Comment: I don't think that is correct though.  I have this code on a local environment with my domain setup as dev.my-local.com.  When I run this javascript on the page, I'm getting a 1, meaning that [@StoreName] is found:

`thisURL = window.document.location.href.toString();
alert(thisURL.search("[@StoreName]"));`

StoreName is nowhere to be found in the URL, so where is it coming from?

Comment: That's hard to say without seeing more code... you picked the right two-line snippet, but no two-line snippet can give the big picture. It sounds like maybe some preprocessing is going on that does in fact run `[@StoreName]` as XPath and drops the result in seamlessly before `search()` actually executes, but I can't say how.